# Scala 2.13 migration

Tags: scala, playframework, scala-2.13

I am migrating Play 2.8.8 project from Scala 2.12 to 2.13.

I have a really weird error in the Play routes file:

`method right in class Either is deprecated (since 2.13.0): Either is now right-biased, use methods directly on Either`

There is no `.right` calls in the routes file, in the generated Scala routes file or in the related controllers.

Route file:

```
POST          /roles/:id        controllers.Authentication.api.RolesResource.addRoleToAccount(id:models.users.AccountId)
DELETE        /roles/:id        controllers.Authentication.api.RolesResource.removeRoleFromAccount(id:models.users.AccountId)
GET           /roles/:id        controllers.Authentication.api.RolesResource.getRolesForAccount(id:models.users.AccountId)
```

Thanks for any guidance what might be the source of this error.

Comment: Can you share the full error with the related line of code?

Comment: Likely the error is in the `Routes.scala` file generated from the `routes` file. Did you clean and recompile the project?

Comment: The errors are in each line in this routes file. And of course I cleaned everything. I’ve already said that I’ve also checked the generated Scala route file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is in `play.core.routing.GeneratedRouter` class.

From my route file this method:

```
    (for {
a1 <- pa1.value.right
 a2 <- pa2.value.right}
      yield (a1, a2))
      .fold(badRequest, { case (a1, a2) => generator(a1, a2) })
  }
```

It contains calls to deprecated `.right` function.